# Web Browser in hybris

Tags: web, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to integrate a web browser in Hybris. I've tried in simple HTML for opening a browser as a pop-up. I'm trying the same in Hybris opening a web browser as a popup.
Could that be achievable? Please suggest me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? add the sample example which you have tried successfully with HTML.

Comment: i'm trying to get the assets for products from external AEM DAM system using asset picker. i've used asset picker(js) for picking an asset from AEM DAM in simplet html

Comment: Do you mean an iframe ?

Comment: Here the requirement is: pop-up window